# Proper disposal of WebSocket in a WebSocketContext

Tags: asp.net, websocket, dispose

In ASP.NET, when the handler you provide to [HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.acceptwebsocketrequest.aspx) gets a [AspNetWebSocketContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.websockets.aspnetwebsocketcontext.aspx), should you dispose the context's [WebSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.websockets.aspnetwebsocketcontext.aspx) when you are done with it? Or does the web socket get disposed automatically, perhaps after you call [WebSocket.CloseAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.closeasync.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not dispose the web socket. In fact you cannot. [AspNetWebSocket.Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.websockets.aspnetwebsocket.dispose.aspx) always throws a `NotSupportedException`. The summary and exception sections of the MSDN documentation are incorrect. Fortunately, the remarks section is helpful:

> ASP.NET automatically calls the Dispose method on a AspNetWebSocket
>   object to release any resources that remain after your code has
>   finished executing.